# How to elegantly store f-strings as templates with default values

Tags: python

I have a bunch of f-strings as templates for printing labels. Placeholders in those f-stings would be filled with entries for the label. A part of that f-string could look like this:

```py
template_1 = f"""
^FH\^FDLA,{identifier}^FS
^FT145,51FD{name}^FS^CI27
"""
```

For each of those fields (in this case identifier and name) I need defaults, if no value is provided. Those defaults are not the same for each label, even if they have the same variable name.

At the moment the only (imo ugly) solution I can come up with, is to use if/else statements to set the defaults and then use a giant dict for the f-strings. This might look somethin like this (in some function):

```py
if template == "template_1":
    if name is None:
        name = "name"
    if project is None:
        project= "project"
elif template == "template_2":
    if name is None:
        name = "different name"
    if person is None:
        person = "some person"

temmplates = {
    "template_1" : f"""
    as{name}{project}
    """,
    "template_2" : f"""
    asflkjasdf{person}{name}
    """,
}
```

There must be a better way to dynamically fill some f-sting templates with values and provide default values for that. Maybe using a class or something? But I just can't get it figured out. Bonus on top would be, if I could store those f-stings and defaults in a toml file, but one problem at a time :)

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: You’re really looking for a templating language, not f-strings. For example Jinja2.

Comment: Or even normal strings with the `.format()` method might suit your use case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
class Template:
    def __init__(self, template_string, defaults):
        self.template_string = template_string
        self.defaults = defaults

    def render(self, **kwargs):
        context = {**self.defaults, **kwargs}
        return self.template_string.format(**context)


templates = {
    "template_1": Template("^FH\^FDLA,{identifier}^FS\n^FT145,51FD{name}^FS^CI27", {"name": "name", "project": "project"}),
    "template_2": Template("asflkjasdf{person}{name}", {"name": "different name", "person": "some person"})
}

template = templates["template_1"]
rendered_label = template.render(identifier="ID123", name="John Doe")
print(rendered_label)
```

Comment: Could you rename `test` to something more idomatic? Maybe `Template`?

Comment: Thanks! I upvoted already, just wanted to avoid seeing this with a class named `test` in a codebase I'm working on 20 years from now lol

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind from now to avoid generic titles @Zachiah

Comment: thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for, just tested it and it works beautifully :)